# Is there a way to load AngularJS not from an HTML file (in a Firefox addon main.js file)?

Tags: firefox-addon, angularjs, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox extension using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and I'm trying to use some of the AngularJS services inside my main.js file. I use `require()` to include the relevant modules and `angular.bootstrap()` to initialize the modules.

However, I always get the following error:

> Reference Error: window is not defined

Is there anything else I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS isn't really meant for this kind of environment - it is an MVC framework and in your case V (the view) is missing. You don't tell what you want to use AngularJS for but you might want to consider using it in your content scripts rather than `main.js`.

That said, AngularJS is often using `window` simply as a means to access the global object. This is easy enough to fix, the next-to-last line of AngularJS source code says:

```js
})(window, document);
```

This should be changed into:

```js
})(this, document);
```

This will at least allow the functions to proceed that don't really require a view. Of course you would still need to remove the last line (the one attempting to insert a stylesheet into the document) and export the `angular` variable instead:

```js
exports.angular = angular;
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much detail so I am unsure if this suggestion fits with what you want to do. If you want to use some JS libraries that require a DOM and don't want to show a document to the user, consider using the page-worker module:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/page-worker.html

You will need to set up event-driven communications between the worker and main.js, as with any other content document used with SDK code:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/events.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to get window object via
`var window = require("window-utils").activeBrowserWindow;`?

Comment: handling window objects in add-on code is not a great idea without some boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

What is the view that you are trying to update? You should be able to provide `angular.bootstrap` with some non-root element to start compiling from. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap

If you're using some service that relies on window, you also might need to supply your own tweaked `$window` service. [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24window)